# "Input was" or "Input were"

Tags: grammar

Should I use *was* or *were*?

The context of the sentence is:

> Your input was/were invaluable as it helps to streamline our processes.

Answer (score 1):

You have answered your own question:

> The context of the sentence is:
>
> > **Your input** was/were invaluable as **it** helps to streamline our processes.

You are treating **Your input** as equal to **it**, which is singular.